# Sharepoint 1 feature to deploy all lists or 1 feature per list

Tags: list, sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-feature

What is the best practice when deploying lists using features.

Should i have 1 feature for deploying all list definitions and instance or 1 feature per each list definition and instance that i want to deploy ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that decision depends on your lists, relation between lists and specifically on your problem domain and design.

But usually, I try to placing list definitions in the same feature, where the lists have some kind of strong logical dependency on each other. For example, if one of the columns you use is a lookup column to another list, then put them in same feature.

Also, you might consider that if they are used in implementation of same use case, such that the use case implemented in a specific package has all of its definitions installed in the same feature.

On the other hand, using seperate features might be more desirable when modularity is a stronger requirement. Keep in mind that you'll need to install and activate all the features, which can be a problem if you have too many list definitions & features.

Problem domain is of great importance in this decision, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Le me keep it short :) Do it in one feature.

Do it in one feature, even if you have so many list and multiple modules (finance, HR etc ) because you will always have some list common for all modules (e.g Employee)
Even if you don't have dependencies between your list, i would still recommend you to use one feature just to make your life easy when you expand your system in future and introduced dependencies(lookup) in future